# Time distribution of Twitter data

Tags: python, functional-programming, matplotlib, twitter

The `tweepy.models.Status` class creates a 'tweet' object, it has attribute `.created_at` which is the posting time of the tweet in the form of Python `datetime` object.

Here is the case, I have a function `time_distribution(tweets, **kwargs)` which calculates the distribution of the tweets by time. The function is at the end of this post.

Here is an example implementation, we may use the samples from [statistweepy](https://github.com/anbarief/statistweepy/tree/master/samples) which is about 3000 tweets of @CocaCola_ID twitter account, stored in a `.npy` file. Each 'tweet' is a `tweepy.models.Status` object.

Example:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = list(numpy.load('CocaCola_ID_3093samples_hour_min_21_50_date_24_6_2018.npy'))

dist_only = time_distribution(data, unit = 'hour')
print(dist_only)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
dist_and_plot = time_distribution(data, cont_hist = (ax, 20), unit = 'hour')
plt.show()
```

With argument `cont_hist = (ax, n)`, the function also returns a histogram with `n` number of bins to be plotted on top of `ax`.

My question :

- How to write it better? (sustainable, convenience, readable, compact)
- How to optimize the performance?

---

```
import operator
import itertools

def time_distribution(tweets, unit = 'hour', output = 'frequency', cont_hist = False):

    if not any([unit == 'year', unit == 'month', unit == 'day', unit == 'hour']):
        raise AssertionError(' The argument unit must be one of \'year\',  \'month\',  \'day\', or \'hour\'. ')

    unicity_key = operator.attrgetter('created_at.'+unit)
    tweets = sorted(tweets, key=unicity_key)
    distribution = {}

    for time, time_tweets in itertools.groupby(tweets, key=unicity_key):

        time_tweets = list(time_tweets)

        if output == 'frequency':

            distribution[time] = len(time_tweets)
            fy = lambda x: x

        elif output == 'tweets':

            distribution[time] = time_tweets
            fy = lambda x: len(x)

        else:

            raise AssertionError(' The argument output must be either \'frequency\', or \'tweets\'. ')

    if cont_hist:

        axes = cont_hist[0]

        if unit == 'year':

            xt = [tweet.created_at.year + (tweet.created_at.month + (tweet.created_at.day + tweet.created_at.hour/24)/30)/12 for tweet in tweets]

        elif unit == 'month':

            xt = [(tweet.created_at.month + (tweet.created_at.day + tweet.created_at.hour/24)/30) for tweet in tweets]

        elif unit == 'day':

            xt = [(tweet.created_at.day + tweet.created_at.hour/24) for tweet in tweets]

        elif unit == 'hour':

            xt = [tweet.created_at.hour + (tweet.created_at.minute + tweet.created_at.second/60)/60 for tweet in tweets]

        a = int(min(xt)) + 1
        b = int(max(xt)) + 1

        ticks = range(a-1, b+2)

        histogram = axes.hist(xt, bins = cont_hist[1])
        axes.set_xticks(ticks)
        axes.set_xticklabels([str(i) for i in ticks])
        axes.set_xlabel(unit)
        axes.set_ylabel('frequency')

        return distribution, histogram

    return distribution
```

---

Plot result :

[image]